# function return resultset, get in another class - JAVA

Tags: java, function, return, resultset

I am new in Java. I am doing this thing it creates error, please let me know why I am going in this function **dispatchUncaughtException**. Am I doing right ? If I am not so how can this thing possible ?

This is **dataCollection Class**

```
public class dataCollection {

    private ResultSet my_rs1 =  null;

    public ResultSet mydata()
    {
        try
        {
            String get_data_query = "SELECT * FROM my_table ";
            my_rs1 = cn.stmt.executeQuery(aggregator_data_query);

        } catch(SQLException SQLex)
        {
            System.out.println("SQL Error: " + SQLex.getMessage());
        }

        return my_rs1;        

    }

}
```

**This is callingClass // where we call ResultSet**

```
public class callingClass
{
    dataCollection dc = new dataCollection;
    private ResultSet my_call_data = dc.mydata();
    while(my_call_data.next())
    {
        //Code Here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sms_sender.dataCollection.aggregator_data(dataCollection.java:29)
    at sms_sender.threadClass.run(threadClass.java:27)
```

Comment: The second snippet will not compile ... I guess a typo. Can you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: Try doing public ResultSet my_rs1 =null; in dataCollection class ,it might be possible you are trying to access private member outside the scope

Comment: What is stacktrace ? :(

Comment: @ajitksharma .. No I do it public .. but result is same.

Comment: [What is stack trace]   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: read the above link and past your stack trace here

Comment: @ALL Please check .. stack trace .. Code which is written in question is example but almost similar.

Comment: You have you error with the stack trace now. Check the line 29 of dataCollection -> NullPointerException means you have probably not initialized correctly a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your parameter :

```
String get_data_query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
my_rs1 = cn.stmt.executeQuery(get_data_query);
```

**Edit:**
Step 2 => 
Check your db connection its working properly. i think your stmt is empty or incorrect.

Comment: Yeah it was my written mistake. I correct it, but still problem is same. :(

Comment: Thx .. It run :). Statement stmt was null.

Answer (score 0):

code should be in function or block in java.

```
    public class callingClass
    {
        dataCollection dc = new dataCollection;
        private ResultSet my_call_data;

        public void showData(){
        my_call_data = dc.mydata();
         while(my_call_data.next()){
            //Code Here
         }
       }

    }
```

Comment: are you facing the same problem.?

Comment: Almost yes ! I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are not catching an Exception so the [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) will try to forward this Exception.

First try to catch the Exception and give us the stacktrace :

```
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(); // if you are not using a logger like log4j just print it.
}
```

Then i would recommend that you read more about [Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

And finally, as a notice class names should begin by a Capital letter see [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Good reading :)

PS : i did not notice that your code was not in a method / function, but i suppose this is just a bad edit as the class would not even compile.